# Node.js MongoDb find function ignores wait

Tags: node.js, promise, mongodb-.net-driver

I need the callback function of `find` from `Node.js mongodb 3.1.6` to be triggered before the return statement of an async function, however the return statement is called before the callback function even-though there is a wait in front.

```
async function(myId) {
  const myObject = MyObject()
  await collection.find({where: {id: myId}}, async (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          logger.error('error');
        }
        myObject.add(results);
      });
  return myObject
}
```

I have seen some examples where instead of `find(query, callback)` the pattern `find(query).toArray()` was used. But this doesn't run at all in my case. We use `Node.js mongodb 3.1.6` with `loopback-connector-mongodb` maybe this is related to the problem.

Comment: hmm, the 3.1 documentation for [`collection.find`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#find) doesn't say it even allows a callback and always returns a cursor

Comment: [`Cursor.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#toArray) returns a promise, which is a requirement for the `await` keyword to work correctly with asynchronous methods.

Comment: I must admit this makes perfect sense. I can not understand if the find I use is somehow different because I import `loopback-connector-mongodb` (it is a big project and I am not in charge of choosing the libraries and the imports are confusing) however `toArray()` does not work and the callback I give to find is called simply much later, I don't know if this is because it sees it as options which I don't know what it does with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mongo doesn't provide a promise-answering function, then promisify this one yourself.  Neither that promise-creating wrapper nor the anonymous callback it uses should be declared async, but the caller should....

```
function findById(collection, myId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    collection.find({where: {id: myId}}, (err, results) => {
      (err)? reject(err): resolve(results);
    });
  });
}

// now callers can use the async await pattern...
async someFunction() {
  try {
    let myId = // ...
    let collection = // ...
    let results = await findById(collection, myId);
    // do something with results
  } catch (err) {
    // error
  }
}
```

The key idea is that collection.find with the callback isn't eligible for await, because it doesn't return a promise. The anonymous callback function you pass to it isn't an async function... it does its work right away, as soon as find calls it back. So we build a promise around mongo, then use the new async/await syntax with that promise.

Comment: This works but I am still confused as to why my code behaves the way it does. After the comments from @kmdreko and others I assume I have a mess with the imports and this is the cause.

Comment: The key idea is that collection.find with the callback isn't eligible for await, because it doesn't return a promise.  The anonymous callback function you pass to it isn't an async function... it does its work right away, as soon as find calls it back.  So my advice here is to build a promise around mongo, then use the new async/await syntax with that promise.

Comment: I see, I was expecting find to behave like a promise while it is none. Could you add this to your answer? I know I marked it already but this also explains why my code was not working.